# Can I combine all the sections "Objdump -S -d elf-file" generate into a re-assemble capable file?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, elf, disassembly, objdump

THe elf file is static linked

and currently the objdump's output is something like:

```
Disassembly of section: .init:

xxxxxx

Disassembly of section: .plt:

xxxxxx

Disassembly of section: .text:

xxxxxx
```

basically what I want to achieve is

"elf-file -(disassemble by objdump)-> assemble file --(re-compile)--> **same functionality**"

I don't need the re-compiled binary has the binary content same as the original one, only **same functionality** is enough.

After a quick search, basically the answer is **no**, and they argued that disassemble file lost some stuff like **symbolic information** or others, but I think by static link, I can get rid of this issue...

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`objdump -S -d elf-file` is not usually sufficient, as it lacks `.data` section.

But it seems that `objdump -S -D elf-file` is sufficient.

To try this, I wrote a small x86-64 assembly file that uses `extern printf`, assembled it with YASM without debug symbols and linked with GCC.

```
[bits 64]

; yasm -f elf64 -m amd64 1st_generation.asm -o 1st_generation.o; gcc -o 1st_generation 1st_generation.o

section .text
global main
extern printf

main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp,rsp
    lea     rdi,[msg]
    mov     rsi,[num]
    xor     eax,eax
    call    printf
    mov     eax,60
    xor     ebx,ebx
    syscall

section .data

msg db 'abcdef = %d', 0xa, 0
num dd 1337

testmsg1:
db "test 01", 0x0a, 0
```

Then I disassembled it with `objdump -S -D -M intel elf-file >objdump_output.txt`. `-M intel` produces the disassembly in Intel format. AT&T would work too, but I prefer Intel format for its clarity.

Then I wrote a small `gawk` program `objdump_to_asm` to convert the disassembly produced by `objdump -S -D -M intel elf-file >objdump_output.txt` into a suitable format for YASM. Assumes x86-64 code and `main` as entry point. Can be easily edited to different kinds of environment (x86 is trivial, others may need more work). Usage `./objdump_to_asm objdump_output.txt`. Interestingly 1st generation executable has size of 6598 bytes, whereas 2nd generation executable has size of only 6496 bytes. 3rd generation assembly code is identical with the 2nd generation assembly code.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    disassembly_of_section_string = "Disassembly of section ";

    sections_to_discard[1] = ".interp";
    sections_to_discard[2] = ".note.ABI-tag";
    sections_to_discard[3] = ".note.gnu.build-id";
    sections_to_discard[4] = ".dynsym";
    sections_to_discard[5] = ".dynstr";
    sections_to_discard[6] = ".hash";
    sections_to_discard[7] = ".gnu.hash";
    sections_to_discard[8] = ".gnu.version";
    sections_to_discard[9] = ".gnu.version_r";
    sections_to_discard[10] = ".rela.dyn";
    sections_to_discard[11] = ".rela.init";
    sections_to_discard[12] = ".eh_frame";
    sections_to_discard[13] = ".dynamic";
    sections_to_discard[14] = ".got";
    sections_to_discard[15] = ".got.plt";
    sections_to_discard[16] = ".jcr";
    sections_to_discard[17] = ".init_array";
    sections_to_discard[18] = ".comment";
    sections_to_discard[19] = ".note.gnu.gold-version";

    number_of_sections_to_discard = length(sections_to_discard);

    sections_to_handle[1] = ".plt";
    sections_to_handle[2] = ".text";
    sections_to_handle[3] = ".data";
    sections_to_handle[4] = ".bss";

    number_of_sections_to_handle = length(sections_to_handle);

    blocks_to_discard_in_text[1] = "<call_gmon_start>:";
    blocks_to_discard_in_text[2] = "<deregister_tm_clones>:";
    blocks_to_discard_in_text[3] = "<register_tm_clones>:";
    blocks_to_discard_in_text[4] = "<__do_global_dtors_aux>:";
    blocks_to_discard_in_text[5] = "<frame_dummy>:"
    blocks_to_discard_in_text[6] = "<__libc_csu_fini>:"
    blocks_to_discard_in_text[7] = "<__libc_csu_init>:"
    blocks_to_discard_in_text[8] = "<_start>:"; # !!!

    number_of_blocks_to_discard_in_text = length(blocks_to_discard_in_text);

    blocks_to_handle_in_text[1] = "main"

    number_of_blocks_to_handle_in_text = length(blocks_to_handle_in_text);

    blocks_to_handle_in_data[1] = "__dso_handle"

    number_of_blocks_to_handle_in_data = length(blocks_to_handle_in_data);

    externs_to_handle[1] = "printf";

    number_of_externs_to_handle = length(externs_to_handle);

    hexdump_start_byte = 11;
    disassembly_start_byte = 33;

    current_section = "";

    getline;
    getline;

    file_format_index = match($0, "file format elf64-x86-64")
    if (file_format_index > 0)
    {
        print "[bits 64]";
    }
}
{
    match_index = 0; # 0 : no match, > 0 : match.
    i = 1;           # index to sections_to_handle .
    while (i <= number_of_sections_to_handle)
    {
        match_index = match($0, (disassembly_of_section_string sections_to_handle[i]));
        if (match_index > 0) # we have a section to handle.
        {
            current_section = sections_to_handle[i];
            getline;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    match_index = 0; # 0 : no match, > 0 : match.
    i = 1;           # index to sections_to_discard .
    while (i <= number_of_sections_to_discard)
    {
        match_index = match($0, (disassembly_of_section_string sections_to_discard[i]));
        if (match_index > 0) # we have a section to discard.
        {
            current_section = sections_to_discard[i];
            getline;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (match (current_section, ".plt"))
    {
        match_index = 0; # 0 : no match, > 0 : match.
        i = 1;           # index to externs_to_handle.

        while (i <= number_of_externs_to_handle)
        {
            match_index = match($0, ("<" externs_to_handle[i] "@plt>:"));

            if (match_index > 0)    # we have an extern to handle.
            {
                print "extern " externs_to_handle[i];
                getline;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (match (current_section, ".text"))
    {
        match_index = 0; # 0 : no match, > 0 : match.
        i = 1;           # index to the blocks of section .text . 

        while (i <= number_of_blocks_to_handle_in_text)
        {
            match_index = match($0, ("<" blocks_to_handle_in_text[i] ">:"));

            if (match_index > 0)    # we have a block to handle.
            {
                print "section .text";
                print "global main";
                print blocks_to_handle_in_text[i] ":";
                getline;

                while ((length ($0)) > 0)
                {
                    disassembly_without_hex_bytes = substr($0, disassembly_start_byte);
                    disassembly_without_hex_bytes = gensub(/PTR /, "", "g", disassembly_without_hex_bytes);
                    disassembly_without_hex_bytes = gensub(/(ds:)([a-z0-9]*)/, "[\\2]", "g", disassembly_without_hex_bytes);

                    match_index = 0; # 0 : no match, > 0 : match.
                    j = 1;           # index to externs to handle.

                    while (j <= number_of_externs_to_handle)
                    {
                        match_index = match(disassembly_without_hex_bytes, ("<" externs_to_handle[i] "@plt>"));

                        if (match_index > 0)    # we have an extern to handle.
                        {
                            current_extern_to_handle = externs_to_handle[j];
                            "echo '" disassembly_without_hex_bytes "' | sed 's/\\([0-9]*\\)\\( <\\)\\(" current_extern_to_handle "\\)\\(@plt>\\)/\\3/g'" |& getline disassembly_without_hex_bytes;
                            close("echo '" disassembly_without_hex_bytes "' | sed 's/\\([0-9]*\\)\\( <\\)\\(" current_extern_to_handle "\\)\\(@plt>\\)/\\3/g'");
                            break;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }

                    if (match(disassembly_without_hex_bytes, "data32") != 1)
                    {
                        print disassembly_without_hex_bytes;
                    }
                    getline;
                }
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (match (current_section, ".data"))
    {
        match_index = 0; # 0 : no match, > 0 : match.
        i = 1;           # index to the blocks of section .data .

        while (i <= number_of_blocks_to_handle_in_data)
        {
            match_index = match($0, ("<" blocks_to_handle_in_data[i] ">:"));

            if (match_index > 0)    # we have a block to handle.
            {
                print "section .data";
                getline;

                while ((length ($0)) > 0)
                {
                    getline;
                    hexdump_only = substr($0, hexdump_start_byte, (disassembly_start_byte - hexdump_start_byte));
                    hexdump_only = gensub(/([[:alnum:]]+)/, "0x\\1", "g", hexdump_only);
                    hexdump_only = gensub(/(0x[[:alnum:]]+)( )(0x[[:alnum:]]+)/, "\\1, \\3", "g", hexdump_only);
                    hexdump_only = gensub(/(0x[[:alnum:]]+)( )(0x[[:alnum:]]+)/, "\\1, \\3", "g", hexdump_only);
                    if (match (hexdump_only, "0x") > 0)
                    {
                        print "db " hexdump_only;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Executing `./objdump_to_asm objdump_output.txt >2nd_generation.asm` produces the following assembly file. Assembles with YASM, links with GCC. The assembled and linked executable is not identical with the original, actually it's 6496 bytes, whereas the original executable has size of 6568 bytes.

```
[bits 64]
extern printf
section .text
global main
main:
push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp
lea    rdi,[0x401958]

mov    rsi,QWORD [0x401965]

xor    eax,eax
call   printf
mov    eax,0x3c
xor    ebx,ebx
syscall 

section .data
db 0x61                     
db 0x62                     
db 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66           
db 0x20, 0x3d, 0x20, 0x25, 0x64, 0x0a       
db 0x00, 0x39                   
db 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x74, 0x65         
db 0x73, 0x74                   
db 0x20, 0x30                   
db 0x31, 0x0a                   
db 0x00, 0x00
```

Answer (score 1):

At least some "middle stage" is probably needed to make the reloc-info into assembler accepted form. What I have seen (Linux), the code is partially (internally) linked, and the label info is then replaced by reloc info.

You see them as jumps to the jump instructions themselves and reloc info about what to do to the jump target address at load time.